# How to highlight 2 bars with different colors in an Altair bar graph?

Tags: python, pandas, altair

I would like to highlight two different bars in an Altair bar graph. However, each one has to have a different color, based on a different condition.

## The basics:

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"fruits": ["banana", "plum", "apple", "lime"], "values": [10, 6, 8, 5]})

plot = (
    alt.Chart(df)
    .mark_bar()
    .encode(
        x=alt.X("fruits", sort="y"),
        y="values"))

apple_plot = plot.encode(color=alt.condition(alt.datum.fruits == "apple", alt.value("red"), alt.value("navy")))

banana_plot = plot.encode(color=alt.condition(alt.datum.fruits == "banana", alt.value("yellow"), alt.value("navy")))

apple_plot | banana_plot
```

## The result so far

[image: bar graphs]

## What I tried

```
apple_banana_plot = plot.encode(
    color=alt.condition(
        alt.datum.fruits == "apple",
        alt.value("red"),
        alt.condition(
            alt.datum.fruits == "banana",
            alt.value("yellow"),
            alt.value("navy"))))

apple_banana_plot
```

## The error I got:

> TypeError: type object got multiple values for keyword argument 'condition'

...which means I cannot use a condition inside another.

## The result I expect

[image: expected]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:
Basically, you define `color` with two parameters:

- domain - the list of values in the categorical column
- range - specific values of colors

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"fruits": ["banana", "plum", "apple", "lime"], "values": [10, 6, 8, 5]})

plot = (
    alt.Chart(df)
    .mark_bar()
    .encode(
        x=alt.X("fruits", sort="y"),
        y="values",
    color=alt.Color('fruits',
                     scale=alt.Scale(
                         domain=df.sort_values(['values'])['fruits'].tolist(),
                         range=['navy', 'navy', 'red', 'yellow']))))
plot
```

Comment: It is that that I was looking for. Before I read this answer I tried to define a new column for the colors and to use `color=alt.Color('colors', scale=None)`. It worked for the colors but I missed the legend. Answer accepted.