# Streamlit: Using Multiple Conditions and Colors for Bars in a Bar Chart

Tags: python, streamlit, altair

I'm using Streamlit to create a dashboard. I have a bar graph using altair and [in their docs](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/bar_chart_with_highlighted_bar.html), they show how to color a bar if it meets a condition. I don't see anything on how to color multiple bars and with multiple, different conditions.

I aiming to use three different colors based on three different conditions but I can't get it to work.

I've tried variations of the following:

```
color = alt.condition(
                alt.datum.Team == ['Arsenal', 'Manchester City'],
                alt.value('orange'),
                alt.value('steelblue') 
            )
```

I'm also not sure how to include multiple conditions for different colors.

The top four teams should be one color, the 5th placed team another color and the last three teams another color.
[image]

Comment: I find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72037577/how-to-highlight-2-bars-with-different-colors-in-an-altair-bar-graph) to be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Rather than

```
                alt.datum.Team == ['Arsenal', 'Manchester City'],
```

I think you want

```
                alt.datum.Team in ['Arsenal', 'Manchester City'],
```

Comment: Trying that nets an error: `NotImplementedError: condition predicate of type <class 'bool'>`

Comment: Well, then their "highlight a bar" use case doesn't appear to be a convenient fit for your use case. Fall back to defining a `dict` mapping from team to color (orange or blue).

Comment: I think you're right. I'll have to use a different library.